# How much should I budget for food in Italy?

Tags: budget, food-and-drink, italy

In late November (Thanksgiving) my family will be in Italy!  It will be my wife, my 8 year old son and myself.

We will be there for 10 days.

Our plan is to visit Venice, Florence and Rome.  With a quick half-day in Pisa.

Not all of the hotels provide breakfast so I am assuming the worst and pretending none will.  We haven't booked Rome's hotel yet so I'm not sure.

Anyway, I would like one nice dinner in each of the three big cities (Venice, Florence and Rome).  The other meals could be a mixture of deli's, groceries, cheap pizza, etc.

I don't want touristy food if I can help it.

Now, here' the catcher.  My wife is a little picky and my son if VERY picky on what he eats.  Me, I love all food including anchovies, stinky cheese, etc.

How can I budget for for this?  I literally have no idea how much to take.  We want to eat well but not break the bank.  We're not opposed to buying cereal and milk for breakfast if that can reduce the budget.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you want something a bit nicer than a big mac (for which you can easily find the price in most places worldwide for comparison!), but what's the top end? Michelin 3*? Or not that high? :)

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to tell without knowing your family and their preferences and dietary requirements. I'd suggest finding websites of restaurants in the areas where you'd be residing and check their menus and prices. If you are not opposed to cooking, find what local grocery chains are available. This should give you some ballpark estimate of what kind of prices you should be expecting. I'm sorry if I'm not specific enough, but your question is just too general.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in Italy you can have a very nice meal in range of prices going from 20 Euros for person up to 100 (some top restaurants can be even more expensive), beverages included.
Also in the cheapest places you usually find good quality food (it's difficult to find bad food in Italy).
Regarding your family difficult tastes, usually you can find almost everywhere simple dishes  like pasta or meat that could be a good choice for them.